# Hide MPMoviePlayerController controls on 1+ plays

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I have a MPMoviePlayerController setup:

```
self.moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
[self.moviePlayerController.view setFrame:frame];
// hide controls initially
[self.moviePlayerController setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
[self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayerController.view];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(loadStateChanged:) name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification object:self.
 moviePlayerController];
```

Then when the notification is fired:

```
-(void)loadStateChanged:(NSNotification*)notification {
    if (self.moviePlayerController.controlStyle == MPMovieControlStyleNone) {
        [self.moviePlayerController setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleDefault];
    }
}
```

On initial playback this works great, controls are not shown when playback starts but tapping the view shows the controls.

However, when a movie is already playing and I start playback of another URL, I hide the controls, but they reappear after playback starts of the second movie:

```
[self.moviePlayerController setContentURL:videoURL];
[self.moviePlayerController setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
[self.moviePlayerController play];
```

The notification does fire again and it correctly has a `controlStyle` of `MPMovieControlStyleNone` which I then set to `MPMovieControlStyleDefault`.

Anybody have any experience with this, is there a way to make sure the controls stay hidden on a second playback, but are in fact visible when the user taps the movie view.

Thanks!

Comment: What method is your `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(loadStateChanged:) name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification object:self.
 moviePlayerController];` in?

Comment: @Bot It's `viewDidLoad`, but that's not the issue, since the method does get called.

Comment: I'm asking because you could of been having duplicate observers being triggered. I have had it happen to me before.

Comment: Also note that your notification will be triggered on any buffer state changes. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/MPMovieLoadState  It is likely that the loadState is switching from `playable` to `playthroughOK` which is causing your event to trigger again. Can you add logging to confirm this?

Comment: It does get triggered, but the issue is with different behaviours between first playback and then playback where a video is already playing.